# combination/matrix in latex

Tags: latex

I am trying the write something below in latex and what I am trying seems not working well.

```
\documentclass[10pt,english,8pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Observation equation: 
    
 $\begin{pmatrix}
    PD_{s,t}\\ 
    RR_{s,t} 
\end{pmatrix} = \binom(\gamma_{1}\gamma_{2}) = bla
    
    
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269980/wrong-parentheses-size-in-binom-with-xelatex-and-unicode-math-in-displaystyle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `\binom(...)` is wrong. `\binom` is a macro with two mandatory arguments, so you need to write `\binom{...}{...}`.

Some other comments:

- the closing `$` is missing
- personally I would use the `pmatrix` in both cases to get a more uniform result
- combining the `10pt` and `8pt` class options makes not much sense, they are mutually exclusive. Decide which of the two options you want and then use only this option, not both
- you don't need to load `amsmath`, beamer loads it automatically

---

```
\documentclass[english,8pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Observation equation: 
    
 $\begin{pmatrix}
    PD_{s,t}\\ 
    RR_{s,t} 
\end{pmatrix} = \binom{\gamma_{1}}{\gamma_{2}} = bla
$
    
    
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]